# Missing Dock Icons OSX Mavericks

Tags: macos, mac, boot, dock

First off (this has been happening more and more recently) I open my MBPR 11,3 (OSX 10.9.2) to a black screen - sometimes it has a working cursor. After holding down the Power Button for 5 sec the computer restarts only to give me this dock (missing some but not all Icons):

[image: Missing Dock Items]

And this a couple of days later:
[image]

I haven't nailed down exactly which steps are necessary to get them back, but these are the ones I followed this most recent time:

1. Power Off Computer
2. Power on holding `SHIFT+CONTROL+OPTION` (wait for charger light to turn off then back on) - SMC Reset
3. Boot back up. (Not fixed)
4. Google the problem. Find this page: [discussions.apple.com](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23561916#23561916)
5. Run this command: `mv ~/L*/Application\ Support/Dock/*.db ~/Desktop`
6. Reboot holding: `COMMAND+ALT+P+R`
7. Sometimes I am greeted to default Maverick background and working dock, but other times I am stuck repeating the above steps, booting to a repair disk, and just pressing buttons until something finally works...

Anyone have any idea why this is happening? I know it probably has something to do with the black screen when I wake the computer up. I do not want to re-install OSX and shouldn't have to (I would expect that from Windows but not mac) - on top of the several hours this would add in rebuilding my development environments.

I have Repaired, Verified the Boot disk and Permissions and done everything else I could find in Googling.

Help?

Comment: Whoa - think before you modify that `mv` command to `rm`! The `mv` would have moved the file to a backup on your desktop, like you said, but the way you have it written, `rm` would try to remove (1) the original file and (2) your desktop! In this case it will fail because desktop is a folder and you didn't specify `rm -rf`. In general, however, try to make sure you fully understand a command before modifying and/or executing it.

Comment: So that's why it never could run it... probably a good thing :) Thanks for the catch.